# Квартал в DateTimePicker

Tags: c#

Как добавить квартал в  DateTimePicker?

```
DateTimePicker.ShowUpDown = true;
```

Хочу место календаря названия кварталов. Например: 1 квартал 2018 г. => (после нажатия up button) => 2 квартал 2018 г. => 3 квартал 2018 г. => 4 квартал 2018 г. => 1 квартал 2019 г. и т.д.

Может создать новый класс? Но как? Я не эксперт по с#

Comment: Используйте `ComboBox` вместо `DateTimePicker`. `DateTimePicker` поддерживает только выбор одной конкретной даты

Comment: Никак, Лучше DomainUpDown, но там тоже проблемма, я-же хочу после   4 квартал 2018 г. => 1 квартал 2019 г. и т.д. в Комбо лист будет большым а если использовать DomainUpDown - тоже нужен новый класс

Comment: По кнопкам вверх-вниз в комбобоксе тоже будут меняться текущее значение на предыдущее-следующее. А при желании можете добавить кнопки Up и Down отдельные

Comment: Андрей а как сделать в комбо array {1 квартал,2 квартал,3 квартал,4 квартал} и рядом Год. после увеличения 4 и уменшения 1 менялся год. Помогите плииз

Comment: Например, так: `string[] q = Enumerable.Range(2018, 10).SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Range(1, 4).Select(y => $"{y} квартал {x} г.")).ToArray();` Или так: `string[] q = Enumerable.Range(0, 40).Select(x => $"{(x % 4) + 1} квартал {2018 + x / 4} г.").ToArray();`

Comment: А какой фреймворк? Winforms? WPF?

Comment: Ой, сорри не указал - Winforms